# Matplotlib chart does not display in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I run the following code in PyCharm 3.4.1, and it highlighted `%matplotlib inline` showing syntax error, and I delete the first line, and run, I expect it will prompt me some charts, but it runs normally with `Process finished with exit code 0`， and no charts is showing.

My question is:
1. What is `%matplotlib inline`  use for;
2. How to let pycharm shows matplotlib chart?

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
figsize(11, 9)

import scipy.stats as stats

dist = stats.beta
n_trials = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 15, 50, 500]
data = stats.bernoulli.rvs(0.5, size=n_trials[-1])
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

# For the already prepared, I'm using Binomial's conj. prior.
for k, N in enumerate(n_trials):
    sx = plt.subplot(len(n_trials) / 2, 2, k + 1)
    plt.xlabel("$p$, probability of heads") \
        if k in [0, len(n_trials) - 1] else None
    plt.setp(sx.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    heads = data[:N].sum()
    y = dist.pdf(x, 1 + heads, 1 + N - heads)
    plt.plot(x, y, label="observe %d tosses,\n %d heads" % (N, heads))
    plt.fill_between(x, 0, y, color="#348ABD", alpha=0.4)
    plt.vlines(0.5, 0, 4, color="k", linestyles="--", lw=1)

    leg = plt.legend()
    leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.4)
    plt.autoscale(tight=True)


plt.suptitle("Bayesian updating of posterior probabilities",
             y=1.02,
             fontsize=14)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The `%` notation is for [magic functions](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions).  The particular magic function and argument you reference, `%matplotlib inline`, is meant for an [IPython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%203%20-%20Plotting%20with%20Matplotlib.ipynb) session.  You will get a syntax error using magic functions in a normal python session.

The `%matplotlib` magic function is meant to specify a backend for matplotlib and the argument `inline` will produce an error if you are not in an IPython notebook session.

To show your plot you should use `plt.show` for an interactive window or `plt.savefig` to save it to file.  For example,

```
plt.show()
```

or

```
plt.savefig( 'myfig.png' )
```

Comment: yep.  i was just referencing the function itself, but added some examples.

Comment: yep but better to show the full command or no doubt someone sometime will get confused!

Comment: agreed.  it's easy to forget what the learning experience was like

Answer (score 9):

plot show with some value, helped in providing the window where I was able to see the image. By default the interactive mode was false. I neeed to turn on the interactive mode. 
`plt.interactive(True)`

Add the plt.show command after plotting the graph.

```
plt.show(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

if using an IDE such as Pycharm, instead of using `%matplotlib inline`. Try using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of step 2 just did: plt.show() and 2 of my scatter plots were displayed

Answer (score 2):

`plt.show()` only displays the static PNG form of the plot for me. I had to use 'mpl.use('Qt5Agg')' per this post https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-an-interactive-plot-of-a-pyplot-when-using-pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

I got my plot to show by selecting Edit Configurations... and under Execution, check the box Run with Python console. I just used plt.tight_layout(). I was not in a Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

%matplotlib specifies the backend for matplotlib, and with the argument inline you can display the graph and make the plot interactive.

% is used for representing magic function in python in Pycharm i.e %matplotlib inline- becomes a magic function.

In Pycharm you can directly use

```
plt.show()
```